# Term for non-ARX symmetric-key cryptographic primitive design strategy

Tags: symmetric, terminology, arx

What's the term for describing designing symmetric-key cryptography primitive out of bitwise operations and shifts and rotations?

The closest thing I've found is [this Keccek team's page](https://keccak.team/2017/not_arx.html) calling it NORX, but the linked reference says NORX is actually an AEAD algorithm.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a standard term for that.

Comment: NORX is just a name, not a type of cipher. NORX is actually classified as a duplex sponge based AEAD symmetric cryptographic primitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primitives based purely on bitwise and shift/rotate operations can be described as being based on:

> Binary Polynomials

Bitwise and, or, not, xor are element-wise $\mathbb{F}_2$ additions and subtractions; $n$-bit shift are based on multiplication by $x^n$ reducing $x^w$ where $w$ is the width of the word; rotation are based on multiplication reducing $x^w+1$.